# linear algebra propositions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could you  please help me to prove or disprove this proposition?

 
1. Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix. Then the eigenvalue(s) of $A^TA$ is the same as the eigenvalue(s) of $AA^T$

Comment: You're more likely to get a good response if you describe your attempts and your thoughts about the problems, and what specifically you got stuck on.

Comment: The non-zero eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are necessarily the same..Start with $\lambda \neq 0$ be an eigenvalue of $AA^T$. Then $AA^T x=\lambda x$. Multiplying both sides by $A^T$, we have......... and conclude  that....,

Comment: A good rule of thumb is not to pile on multiple problems in one Question unless you've done enough analysis to know that they have a substantial relationship.  I'm not seeing that to be the case here.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between singular value and eigenvalue?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127500/what-is-the-difference-between-singular-value-and-eigenvalue)  Note that the *eigenvalues* of $A^TA$ are precisely the squares of the *singular values* of $A$.  When $A$ is a square matrix, the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $A$ makes it evident that $A^T$ shares the same singular values.  The desired result follows easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

For 1., you should rewrite the matrices $A$ and $A^T$ in their diagonalised form. Compute the products of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$. What do you notice?

For 2., the characteristic polynomial of a $5\times 5$ matrix will be fifth order. What do you know of complex roots and their conjugates?

For 3., note that $Av=\lambda v$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. What do you know about the definition of the null space and range? Can you make the connection with the eigenvector product?

For 4., I myself am not familiar with the notation $A$~$B$. Like littleO mentioned, try to show your own efforts, this would make the community more responsive, or I would have been able to give a hint on how to approach the problem.

Comment: ~ denotes similarity of two matrices

Comment: In that case, note that similar matrices have a lot of common properties. Connect this to the other propositions.

Comment: Note that 1. is true even if matrix $A$ (equiv. matrix $A^T$) is *not* diagonalizable.

Comment: Since the Question remains closed, I've posted a Comment above, outlining the proof of the generally true claim.