# Principal component Analysis : EVD or SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, data-analysis

Could someone explain what is, from a mathematical practical point of view, PCA in data analysis and when to use it briefly ? and also when to use Eigenvalue decomposition VS Singular value decomposition ?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions; it would be best if you asked them in two separate posts

Comment: Regarding PCA, I strongly recommend you look at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691/128205) on Cross Validated.

Comment: The first one i said just briefly the question is more about the SVD EVD comparison

Comment: For that question, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127500/81360)

Comment: If the post I linked does not give you a satisfactory answer, then it would be helpful if you could edit your post to explain what specific questions about EVD and SVD you have that aren't answered by the post I linked.